# Get Innerhtml of a nestate span element jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just wants to get the inner html of a nestate span tag..

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-SearchByUser-container" title="chowdhury , nayan (nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com)">
    <span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>
    mark john
</span>
```

i need `mark john` and i try =>

```
alert($('#select2-SearchByUser-container').html())
```

i give output/alert something like =>

```
<span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>mark john
```

is there any way that i can get only `mark john`...help please...

Answer (score 0):

To do what you need you can retrieve the last textNode in the element, like this:

```js
var text = $('#select2-SearchByUser-container').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
}).last().text().trim();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-SearchByUser-container" title="chowdhury , nayan (nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com)">
    <span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span> mark john
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

https://jsfiddle.net/4nwp25Le/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var node = $('#select2-SearchByUser-container').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; // text node
  });
  alert(node.text());
});
```

Comment: also how can i change $('#select2-SearchByUser-container').text('hi john');

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not good so far, if possible fix that so that you can get different spans for them.

If you don't have control over HTML, can give a try like this

```
$('#select2-SearchByUser-container').clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qspoygox/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el = document.getElementById("select2-SearchByUser-container"),
    child = el.firstChild,
    texts = [];

while (child) {
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
        texts.push(child.data);
    }
    child = child.nextSibling;
}

var text = texts.join("");
alert(text);
```

```html
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-SearchByUser-container" title="chowdhury , nayan (nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com)">
    <span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>
    mark john
</span>
```